# How to center the map?

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers

I want to center a map. I have it on "width: 50%;" and it is showing one the left side. How do I do this?

I have tried to create a "wrapper" div on it an set text-align to center. This did not work. I also tried it on the .map class... Anybody tried this before?

```
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.map {
   height: 400px;
   width: 50%;
}
```

The reason i want to do this is because i do not want it to fill the whole screen on my webpage. it should be a smaller size window.

Comment: Try float:none; margin:0 auto,  to your .map class, I hope this css property will work for you map.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margins on your wrapper div.

```
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried with the wrapper. But it did not work.